# TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) plugin for multiple selection from dropdown.

For installation i have done

```
npm install react-select --save
```

which installed latest version 3.0.4  of react-select plugin

My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

import urls from '../../../urls.json';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];
class Reports extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedOption: null,
    };

  }
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };
  componentDidMount() { }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <h2>Reports</h2>
            <hr className="title-separator" />
            <Select
                value={this.state.selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div >
    )
  }
}

export default Reports;
```

[image]

Please help!

Comment: by any chance you're using old create-react-app or it's latest?

Comment: I am using "react": "^15.5.4", ( from package .json file )

Comment: I was not specifically asking react, nvm if you have time just do one thing. Update create-react-app then make new project and then try.

Answer (score 0):

The version of `react-select` you're using isn't compatible with your version of `react`. You can downgrade `react-select` to use v2 by doing the following:

```
npm install react-select@2.4.4
```

For more details about upgrading please see the [v3 upgrade guide](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3585).